# Using FOREACH Loops wpallimport xpath

Tags: wordpress, xpath, woocommerce

So I am trying to import various images from csv file, they are seperated with dashes - but, because the name of the image also contains a dash, it seperates it and it is not importing the link correctly.

So, I why not ? I should use xpath and just get every image.

```
[FOREACH({imagen})]
<img src="{@url}" alt="{.}" />
[ENDFOREACH]
```

This gives me this result:

```
">" target="_blank">http://www.example.com/file-name.jpg
```

I want to get rid of `">" target="_blank">` how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer:

change

```
space dash space
```

to

```
,
```

and this is what I used inside the image form field:

```
[str_replace(" - ", ",", {imagen[1]})]
```